# No sé cómo hacer que mi bot de discord reconozca al usuario que escribió el comando en discord.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, discord.js

Necesito un bot de discord que sea capaz de reconocer al usuario que tecleo un comando, el bot esta programado en discord.js, por mas que busco no logro encontrar como programar esta funcion y espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

En las guias de la documentación de discord.js encontre esto:

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
    
    await interaction.reply(`Your id: ${interaction.user.id}`);
});
```

En el parametro que en este caso lo nombramos `interaction` que nos pasa la callback del evento, nos da toda la información de cómo y donde proviene la petición. Puedes buscar en la documentación mas sobre la propiedad `user`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, le echaré otro vistazo a la documentación pero eso debería ser todo, de nuevo te doy las gracias ya que estuve unos días buscando y no era capaz de encontrar nada.